# Enumerate with empty findall result

Tags: python, xml, for-loop, enumerate, findall

I have an xml file from which I want to count a number of tags with the name 'neighbor'. To be more specific, I want to count only the neighbor-tags, that are direct children of any of the country-tags.

Here are the contents of my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Austria">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <neighbor name="Liechtenstein"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland"/>
        <neighbor name="Italy"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Iceland">
        <hasnoneighbors/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia"/>
        <someothertag>
             <neighbor name="Germany"/>
        </someothertag>
    </country>
    <neighbor name="Jupiter"/>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia"/>
        <country name="SubCountry">
            <rank>12</rank>
            <year>2023</year>
            <neighbor name="NeighborOfSubCountry"/>
        </country>
    </country>
</data>
```

The expected result should be 7. Germany and Jupiter should be left out of the total of 9 tags.

I've written the following piece of code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

totalneighbors = 0
neighborlist = []

for country in root.iter('country'):
    print(f'Country {country.attrib["name"]} contains these neighbors:')
    for index, neighbor in enumerate(country.findall('neighbor')):
        neighborname = neighbor.attrib['name']
        print(f'neighbor no {index+1}, with name {neighbor.attrib["name"]}')
        neighborlist.append(neighbor.attrib['name'])
    print(f"total for this country is {index+1}\n")
    totalneighbors += index+1

print(f'total nr of neighbors in country-nodes is {totalneighbors} according to index-counting')
print(f"but the neighborlist says it's {len(neighborlist)}")
```

I wanted to count the tags with the enumerate-functionality from python, but it's giving me the wrong result (10 instead of 7). I put another way of counting in the code, by adding the 'findall' results to a list, and then using the length of that list. This does give me the correct number.

After adding some print statements in the code, I figured out where things go wrong; Iceland has no neighbors, but the print-statement shows that the index is still 3. It looks as if the index from the previous loop was never reset, and it just uses that 3 again, even though 'findall' should find nothing.

So my question is: What am I doing wrong? Why does 'enumerate' not give me 0 when 'findall' finds nothing? Am I using it wrong? Or is it just not possible when combined with an empty search result?

I hope someone can clarify what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in Iceland not having a neighbor, as you said. The first country has three neighbors, so the `index` will have the value of 2 after running the first `for` loop. But the loop won't execute for Iceland, because findall returns an empty list. so the `index` value would still have the value of the previous country.

You can set the `index` to `-1` before the `for` loop. That way your code works fine. Because nothing will be added to the `totalneighbors` if the country has no neighbor.

```
# ...
print(f'Country {country.attrib["name"]} contains these neighbors:')
index = -1
for index, neighbor in enumerate(country.findall('neighbor')):
# remiander of the code
```

---

But overall, I recommend using the `lxml` package and XPath.
here you can find the docs: https://lxml.de/parsing.html

for your purpose using XPath is the best option. You can find more information here:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

the code using `lxml` would look like something like this:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse("/path/to/file.xml")
neighbors = root.findall(".//country/neighbor") # this xpath finds all the neighbors exactly after country
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I know where the problem lies, which I also explained in the problem description. Thanks for your suggestion of using './/country/neighbor' (which doesn't even need lxml by the way).
The thing is that I use the routine of going through each country and collecting its neighbor-children for creating a dictionary. It would be helpful to also be able to count them at the same time using enumerate. But maybe that is simply not possible if empty lists are returned, and I'll have to use a separate command for counting.

Comment: @Fey010 I recommended `lxml` because I have good experience using that, not just because of XPath. You can set the `index` to `-1` before the `for` loop if you wanna use `enumerate`. I think that way your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks mate. Setting a value before starting the loop fixed it for me! Perhaps you can edit your original answer to include this solution. That way I can select it as the solution to my question.